# Resolution Issue when creating an MPEG4 video from images (Windows Media Foundation)

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation

Currently I am using the Media Foundation SDK to convert Images to a H.264 video using the following example from Microsoft.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819477(v=vs.85).aspx

I have encountered an issue when adjusting the MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE of the media type object used for input,  it would seem that if the resolution is higher then monitor the computer is connected to the call to SetInputMediaType for the IMFSinkWriter object returns an HRESULT error code 0xc00d36b4 which means invalid MediaType, which makes me wonder if any MediaType you create is limited by your resolution?  The differences in my code from the example are the following constants defined at the top.

```
const UINT32 VIDEO_WIDTH = 2048;
const UINT32 VIDEO_HEIGHT = 1088;
const GUID   VIDEO_ENCODING_FORMAT = MFVideoFormat_H264;
```

Comment: 0xc00d36b4 is MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE. But I dont know MF so can't help you further.

Comment: Thanks for identifying the HRESULT code.

Comment: My guess would be that it's exceeding max supported resolution 1920×1088 resolution (2048 > 1920). MSDN  makes us guess because Microsoft reserved the right to choose "proper" encoder among possibly multiple installed at their discretion. And hence, restriction might vary, even though you are likely to be interested in inbox system encoder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure that Windows H.264 encoder has a max resolution depending on your version of Windows. Try encoding to 1920 x 1080.

The max resolution of your H.264 encoder is likely independent from your screen resolution.

Comment: After looking more at the documentation for Media Foundation I saw that listed only under H.264 Video Decoder that it was limited to a max resolution of 1920 × 1088 on Windows 7.  So I assume that is probably the case for the encoder as well.